# How to stopService when App is fired

Tags: android, ondestroy

I got a problem puzzling me a long time

Activity **A** in Application **APP**

In onDestroy(), I need to call function **B()** to release some resource, but when I press Home and remove **APP**, onDestroy() can not be callback. What I should do? Do not call **B()** in onPause() or onStop()

PS: I am making a Android MusicPlayer, I need to stopService() when **App** is killed, help!

Comment: Service is going to be stopped when you kill it.  There's nothing that needs to be done.

Comment: I call cancel Notificaiton in Service.onDestroy(), but the notification does not disappear as I wish.